# Email notification to wrong address

Tags: support, email, email-notification

Some time ago (more than a month) I decided to change my email address on Stack Overflow. But funny part is my email notification on topics I'm subscribed to are still being send to the old email address.

When I check my profile though it shows the correct email address. Could anybody give me a helping hand here?

Answer (score 9):

The email address to which notifications are sent is configured separately.

Click on the *preferences* link in your profile and update the *Send emails to* field:

[image: *Send emails to* field in preferences]

The field defaults to your email address attached to your profile.

Comment: Do you know if this setting has been changed? I have the same problem as OP, but I can't see this item in the menu.

Comment: @AntoniParellada: yes, the UI has been updated quite a lot in the past 5 years. There is now a separate *Edit email settings* tab in your preferences.

Comment: If I'm not overlooking anything, though, there is no such thing as "send emails to," which is weird, because I only have one email address in that page, yet I'm receiving emails from stackexchange on a different email account.

Comment: @AntoniParellada: no, the field is simply labelled 'email address' now.

Comment: @AntoniParellada: any of those email addresses used as a login at all?

Comment: No, there is just one email there, and I log in through Google.